# Using toggle Ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

I'm using in my project one toggle button like this:

```
<ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="toggleStatus" pulsado checked="false" (ionChange)="Change_Toggle();"></ion-toggle>
```

When I change status I call to my function "Change_Toggle()". That work fine but I have a problem because when I access to my page I need to check if my button must be active and in this case enabled the button to shown in the interface so I do that like this:

```
this.toggleStatus=true;
```

The problem is that when I change the status, my function "Change_Toggle()" is called and I don't need to call only change status for show in the interface.
Somebody know how can I do that?
Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

Comment: I don't need to call only change status for show in the interface ???? i did not get this line

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say that when I change status like this "this.toggleStatus=true;" automatically my function  "Change_Toggle()" is called, but I don't need that, only do changes in my user interface. Thank for reply me!

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
<ion-toggle pulsado [checked]="toggleStatus" (ionChange)="Change_Toggle();"></ion-toggle>
```

Where `toggleStatus` equals a boolean.